# Bibliography not printing/broken references links after .bib file update

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am using TexShop to write a thesis using the document class article.
 I was using a bib file which was updating all the references correctly without any errors with the `\autocite` option in the foot note section.

For some reason, when I updated the `.bib` file, the reference unique key would continue to be printed in footnotes but the link to the references was broken and the references did not print in the Bibliography section.

Compiled using:

```
pdflatexmk

bibtex

pdflatexmk

pdflatexmk
```

Code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=nyt}
\bibliography{Thesis_Expose_biblio}
```

Comment: You should rewrite your post into a question and an answer (provided by you). It would be more clear this way.

Comment: You should better learn to use biber correctly as quite a number of biblatex features work only with this backend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ppr and yes Ulrike, this being my first complete document in latex, I hope to improve on it.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) so that the problem can be analysed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this after bit of searching. The change I made to make it work was to replace the backend from biber to bibtex.

Changed code:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=nyt}
\bibliography{Thesis_Expose_biblio}
```

Reran in TexShop:

Typeset `pdflatexmk`
Typeset `bibtex`
Typeset `latex`
Typeset `latex`

I hope this is of use to those who have trouble printing references after making changes to `.bib` file

The file in the entirety could be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Some text. \footnote{Cp. \autocite{key}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```