# .bib file generation is broken

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I use the springer nature latex package ([here](https://www.springernature.com/de/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)) to create a document. After a small change in the library file of my document the bibtex file generation ".bbl" seems to become broken. Before the change, everything runs smoothly.
Removing manually all files (e.g. aux, bbl) I did not see no improvement. Additionally, I tested (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338491/running-bib-file-does-not-generate-bbl-file)) to run 1x pdflatex, 1x bibtex, 2x pdflatex to generate the file, this also failed (no proper PDF but an empty bbl).
The biber function, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245658/bibliography-not-printing-broken-references-links-after-bib-file-update) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564979/bibtex-compilation-error), was tested too. Together with the springer nature document it results in a never ending loop and no document is created.

My assumption is that the error is somewhere in my system, but I do not have any idea where and how to solve it. Therefore, I created a minimal example, see below.

My system is Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS, all packages are up to date. Furthermore, I removed and reinstalled the package texlive-full. Also, I restarted my system. As text editor I use Texstudio.

The standard error is:

```
Process started: bibtex "sn-article".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: sn-article.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file sn-article.aux
(There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "sn-article".tex

Process exited normally
```

The minimal example is:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sn-bibliography.bib}
@article{bib1,
    author      = "Campbell, S. L. and Gear, C. W.",
    title           = "The index of general nonlinear {D}{A}{E}{S}",
    journal     = "Numer. {M}ath.",
    volume      = "72",
    number      = "2",
    pages           = "173--196",
    year            = "1995"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}% Default
%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

Test text \cite{bib1}

\bibliography{sn-bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The relevant line is `I found no \bibstyle command`. You need to add `\bibstyle{XXX}`, where `XXX.bst` is one of the files you find in the `bst` folder of the template. Which one to choose depends on the journal and should be documented somewhere.

Comment: A very minor add-on to @gernot's comment: The name of the so-far missing *user* command is `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks ...

Comment: @Mico -- If the correct name of this command is `\bibliographystyle`, then the error message from BibTeX is misleading, if not outright wrong.  Shouldn't that be reported.  Indeed, the BibTeX documentation consistently refers to "bibstyles", but nowhere does it say how to load one in a document.  A terrible omission, I think.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Indeed, it's not good at all that whereas the user command is `\bibliographystyle`, in the blg file one finds only `\bibstyle`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton bibtex looks for a \bibstyle command in the aux and it can not know which commands LaTeX use to write this \bibstyle into the aux.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- I hadn't dug into the code, so thanks; that makes sense   Is this documented somewhere *other than* in the code?  (Without digging, it's not immediately obvious, and, as evidenced above, can be confusing.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton well the latex companion does mention it ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- Yes it does, but I don't think all new LaTeX users have a copy.

Comment: @Mirco: I added now \bibliographystyle{plain} and everything is working fine, no error messages any more. 
Thanks a lot! :D